# Principle of inclusion exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

In a class of 30 children, 20 studied Portuguese, 14 studied English and 10 studied French. If 8 study none of these 3 languages ​​and none study the 3 languages, how many children study English and French?

How do I approach this problem?

Answer: 2

Comment: There's something wrong with your statement of the problem.  Obviously at least $14$ study English *or* French.  Did you mean to ask how many study English *and* French?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

22 students studied at least one language

Let the number who studied English but neither French nor Portuguese be denoted by $E$, the number who studied only French be $F$, and the number who studied Portuguese be $P$.

Let the number who studied both English and French (but necessarily not Portuguese) be denoted by $EF$, and so forth. We then know that

$$
P+E+F+PE+PF+EF = 22 \\
P+PE+PF = 20\\
E+PE+EF = 14 \\
F+EF+PF = 10 
$$Add the last three equations and subtract from that the first equation, to get
$$
PE + PF + EF = (20+14+10)-22 = 22\\
\implies PF = 22-PE-EF
$$
Then use that in the fourth equation to get
$$ 
F + EF + 22 - PE -EF = 10 \\ \implies PE = F + 12
$$
Plug that into the third equation to get
$$
E + (F+12) + EF = 14 \implies E+F+EF = 2
$$
The problem is flawed, in that $2$ students took English or French or both, so the number that took both English and French has to be negative.

Comment: The problem isn't flawed.  Once you know that $PE+PF+EF=22$, you know that every student who studied any language at all studied exactly $2$ languages ($P+E+F=0$), by substituting into the first equation.  Thus, the $2$ students who studied a language but didn't study Portugese had to have studied both English and French, and because no student studied all three languages, none of the students who studied Portugese also studied English *and* French.